# Numpy: subscribing outermost dimension in multidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am working with multiple multidimensional arrays. Let us consider dummy example for simplicity:

```
 array_list=[np.ones(3), np.ones((3,3,3)), np.ones((3,3)), np.ones(3)]
```

I need to subscribe the outermost dimension of each array in the list. For example, my goal is to set some of the elements to zero according to a specified range in the outermost dimension:

```
array_list[0][0:2]=0
array_list[1][:,:,0:2]=0
array_list[2][:,0:2]=0
array_list[3][0:2]=0
```

In my real application I don't know how many arrays I have and how many dimensions are in there.

I would like to do the task in a for loop:

```
for array in array_list:
    array[???]=0
```

But I am struggling how to implement this if I don't know the dimensionality of each array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Ellipsis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#Ellipsis) to select all dimensions except the last (if there's only 1, nothing is selected).

```
for array in array_list:
    array[..., 0:2] = 0
```

Comment: You know something?  I still don't have a good handle on the `...`

Comment: @piRSquared I remember losing a question to another answerer who did something similar... it really sticks when you learn it that way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The documentation is not very specific, but it works great